# Touch Location and touchesBegan in Xcode 6 [Obj-C --> Swift]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, touchesbegan

I am having trouble creating a function "touchesBegan" and then creating a UIPoint and UITouch constant or variable that holds an x and y coordinate. I have the exact code I want in Objective-C but I do not know what it's equivalent is in Swift. Here is the Objective-C code which I want to basically translate into Swift code...
NOTE: This is a Single View Application, NOT a game... Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (point.x < 160) {
        var = 10;
    }
    else{
        var = 20;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where's the problem?

```
var touch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
var point = touch.locationInView(self.view)

if point.x < 160 {
    var variableName = 10;
}
else{
    var variableName = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As of Swift 1.2, use this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{

    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var point = touch.locationInView(self)

    if point.x < 160 {
        var = 10;
    }
    else{
    var = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 1.2 changed the syntax for touchesBegan. See the [UIResponder Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:).

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

And don't forget to reference the super.

```
super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
```

Here is an edited example of implementing this code from [techotopia.com](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_Touch,_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application#Implementing_the_touchesMoved_Method) which might give you more information on the other three touches functions.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   var touch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
   var point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
   // Insert if statements
   super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in swift 1.2, MendyK's answer is the right one